# Extract Information from Text in R

Tags: regex, r, stringr, named-entity-extraction

I am working on Entity Extraction in R.
I have a `UniqueID` and `Text` field - need to extract location information from the text field.
My Text field has description with location names

```
text <- c("SERANGOON JC","Blk 4","SHELL TAMPINES AVE  4","SENOKO INDUSTRIAL ESTATE","Senoko Estate","Senoko","senok Est.")
```

I have a list of Locations ;

```
Loc <- c("SERANGOON JUNIOR COLLEGE","Block 4","SHELL TAMPINES AVENUE 4","SENOKO INDUSTRIAL ESTATE")
```

Need to match the `loc` and extract those location from the `text` field.In the text field `SENOKO INDUSTRIAL ESTATE` is spelt in different ways `Senoko Estate` or `Senoko` (Half Names) or with spelling mistake `senok Est.` .for all the above mis-spelt and half spelt words - i need to get the exact name from `loc` ie. `SENOKO INDUSTRIAL ESTATE`.

My output would look like:(Extract location from Text field -get correct words for half- spelt and misspelt words)

```
ID   Location
123  SERANGOON JUNIOR COLLEGE|Block 4|SHELL TAMPINES AVENUE 4|SENOKO INDUSTRIAL ESTATE|SENOKO INDUSTRIAL ESTATE|SENOKO INDUSTRIAL ESTATE|SENOKO INDUSTRIAL ESTATE
```

Comment: Is there a function or package to try the above one in R?

Comment: Well, what have you tried? I am don't really know anything about this but why not use [agrep](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/agrep.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is the prettiest way to answer it, but..

```
text <- c("SERANGOON JC","Blk 4","SHELL TAMPINES AVE  4","SENOKO INDUSTRIAL ESTATE","Senoko Estate","Senoko","senok Est.") 

Loc <- c("SERANGOON JUNIOR COLLEGE","Block 4","SHELL TAMPINES AVENUE 4","SENOKO INDUSTRIAL ESTATE")

text <- gsub(".*serang.*", "SERANGOON JUNIOR COLLEGE", text, ignore.case=TRUE)
text <- gsub(".*bl.* 4.*", "Block 4", text, ignore.case=TRUE)
text <- gsub(".*shell.*", "SHELL TAMPINES AVENUE 4", text, ignore.case=TRUE)
text <- gsub(".*senok.*", "SENOKO INDUSTRIAL ESTATE", text, ignore.case=TRUE)


print(text)
```

I didn't put it exactly in the format you requested, but that would be the contents of the second column (aka Location). I used the regex expression ".*" before and after the strings you were looking for in case there are other possibilities/typos. This would make it more robust.

Hope this helps!